# How to write keywords in xpath of elements?

Tags: automation, rpa, g1ant

I am working on some robot where I need to use xpath of some particular element which has keyword "label" in its address, so whatever I am writing after keyword label its robot is taking it as argument of label.
here, it's taking the "by" as argument of label.[image]

```
selenium.click search ‴/html/body/app-root/div[2]/app-rpa1/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/rpa1-field/div/label‴ by xpath
```

Answer (score 1):

G1ANT has some issues with the syntax colouring. Don't worry about the `by` argument being coloured as label, it will be parsed correctly and your script should work fine.